# Configuring Grails to POST using certificate authentication

Tags: java, ssl, grails, ssl-certificate, apache-nifi

I am quite new to working with certificates and security, so pardon me if this is a no-brainer to others. I have followed [this guide](http://grailsblog.objectcomputing.com/deployment/2017/06/28/running-grails-with-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate.html) to set up my Grails application to run on HTTPS with self-signed certificates.

I am trying to establish 2-way SSL with another HTTPS network (a Nifi standalone instance) running on the **same machine**. I can get the Nifi instance to talk to Grails over HTTPS, but I am having issues with Grails talking to Nifi (specifically to a ListenHTTP processor).

**I was hoping someone could advise how to use certificate authentication in Grails when posting over HTTPS.**

Nifi uses certificate authentication; however per the above guide Grails only specifies a single keystore (for receiving requests?) so I'm a bit thrown off. I can successfully CURL to Nifi's REST API by specifying the --cert and --key properties, but since the final product will be a WAR on a client machine I want to set this up the 'right way', and I believe leaving those files on the client machine is a really big no-no for security.

During early development [RestBuilder](http://springsource.github.io/grails-data-mapping/rest-client/api/grails/plugins/rest/client/RestBuilder.html) was sufficient for 2-way comms over HTTP, however, I am unable to find any mention of using it with certificate authentication (only basic authentication is covered in the documentation?).

[HTTPBuilder](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki) shows up a lot when I looked for alternatives, however looking at the [relevant documentation (line 139 'certificate()')](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/blob/master/src/main/java/groovyx/net/http/AuthConfig.java) it states that it takes a whole keystore JKS and password. I think this is close but not quite what I am looking for considering I only have one keystore; I am open to correction here.

Please note that I will be unavailable to respond until at least the day after this question was posted.

Answer (score 0):

When making an outgoing HTTPS connection, if the remote endpoint (in this case Apache NiFi) requires client certificate authentication, the originating endpoint (Grails) will attempt to provide a certificate. The certificate that Grails is using to identify itself as a service is fine to use in this scenario, provided:

1. The certificate either does not have the `ExtendedKeyUsage` extension set, or if it is set, both `ServerAuth` and `ClientAuth` values are present. If `ClientAuth` is missing, the system will not allow this certificate to be used for client authentication, which is the necessary role in this exchange.
2. The certificate has a valid `SubjectAlternativeName` value which matches the hostname it is running on. [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-6.4.4) prescribes that SAN values should be used for certificate identity rather than `Distinguished Name` (`DN`) and `Common Name` (`CN`). So if the Grails app is running on `https://grails.example.com`, the SAN must contain values for `grails.example.com` or `*.example.com`.
3. The certificate must be imported into NiFi's truststore in order to allow NiFi to authenticate a presenter of this certificate.
4. NiFi must have ACL permissions in place for this "user". This can be done through the UI or by modifying the `conf/authorizers.xml` file before starting NiFi for the first time. See [NiFi Admin Guide - Authorizers Configuration](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#authorizer-configuration) for more information.

Your concern for leaving the `cert.pem` and `key.key` files on the client machine is understandable, but the sensitive information contained therein is the same data that's in your keystore. At some point, the private key must be accessible by the Grails app in order to perform HTTPS processes, so having it in the keystore is functionally equivalent (you don't mention having a password on the `*.key` file, but obviously you should have a password on the keystore).